# Integrate $\sin x/(1+\sin x)$, how to?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How can I integrate $\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{\sin x}{1+\sin x}}dx$? I have already tried by applying different trigonometric results.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we write the expression in the following way:
$$\frac{\sin x}{1+ \sin x} = \frac{\sin x(1 - \sin x)}{(1+\sin x)(1 - \sin x)} = \frac{\sin x - (\sin x)^2}{1 - (\sin x)^2} = \frac{\sin x - (\sin x)^2}{(\cos x)^2}
\\= \frac{\sin x}{(\cos x)^2} - (\tan x)^2$$
Do you see how we can integrate these two terms?

Comment: I think the final terms are getting harder to integrate. ;-)

Comment: $\sin x/ (\cos x)^2$ can be integrated by a simple substitution, and $(\tan x)^2$ can be integrated by writing $(\tan x)^2 = [ (\tan x)^2 + 1] - 1$. I think this is a good way to do it if one doesn't know about the Weierstrass substitution

Comment: I see. Thanks :-)

Comment: the result is secx - tanx + x . actually the question was a definite integral with upperlimit Pi/2 so i cannot apply on this result due to presence of secx. works fine with this [link](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=+Sin[x]%2F%281%2Bsin[x]%29&random=false) what is wrong!!!!

Comment: $\sec x - \tan x = (1- \sin x)/(\cos x)$. This is a 0/0-expression when $x = \pi/2$, so you can evaluate it as a limit by using L'hôpital's rule for instance.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Write $\frac{\sin{x}}{1+\sin{x}}$ as
$$\frac{\sin{x}}{1+\sin{x}}= \frac{1+\sin{x}-1}{1+\sin{x}} =1 -\frac{1}{1+\sin{x}} $$

Now subsitute $u=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}$

With this substitution the integral will simplify to

$$\int dx - \int\frac{2}{u^2+2u+1}\,du $$